# PHP: Class Member Variable - Default Value

Tags: php, class

Considering the following:

```
<?php

class Tiger {
    static $stripes;
}

?>
```

What is the value of `Tiger::$stripes`?

Comment: I posted this question/answer because I was fed up looking for the correct answer; I found like 5 stack overflow questions about it, but not even a single one just clearly stated the answer for some reason. I just wanted there to be at least *one* clear answer in the search engines.

Answer (score 0):

### The default value for PHP class member variables is `null`

**`Tiger::$stripes` would be `null`**

```
<?php

class Tiger {
    static $stripes;
}

var_dump( Tiger::$stripes );

?>
```

Outputs:

```
NULL
```

---

Thusly, these two declarations for $stripes are equivalent:

```
static $stripes = null;
  // (equivalent)
static $stripes;
```

Comment: Everytime when you declare a new variable he will be assigned as null; You should try read "isset" documentation to see what's i'm talking about. http://br2.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php